# Definitions of saddle points, nodes and edges

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, implementation

I am working on some algorithm implementation, however being new to image processing, I have some questions about some of the definitions used.

They(in the paper) keep on mentioning a node without prior definition, this means a truepoint with 2 other trueneighbors(out of 8). Am I right ? (this is the general definition of a node pixel)

They define an Edge being the distance between two adjacent nodes where the distance between them is $ \leq \sqrt2 $. What do they mean by that exactly ?

Last they define saddle points being node pixels with the connected edge length has to be $ \geq 3 $ . I don't know what they mean by that

Update: Paper: ROCHADE: Robust Checkerboard Advanced Detection for Camera Calibration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes are the "white" pixels on the centerline image (in image processing they would be called "edge pixels", but here they are seen a the nodes of the adjacency graph).

Edges are the links between 8-neighboring pixels (they are the edges of the adjacency graph).

Saddle points are the nodes having at least 3 neighbors, i.e. candidates for meeting points of the squares (as seen on the "Saddle point mask").

Comment: great answer! could you please maybe clarify what you mean by adjacency graph ?

Comment: The graph of the "is neighbor" relation.

Comment: Thank you yves, I got great results thanks to your help. All i need to do is tweak and optimize! cheers!